# Regex character limit

Tags: php, regex

I'm using URI segments to match a form of ID and basically I want it to match strings of up to 5 characters only.

How do I go about regex for this? This is what I have so far but it doesn't work - which is why I'm here:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9*]{5})(?![a-zA-Z0-9*])/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9*]{1,5}$/
```

or

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9*]{0,5}$/
```

if you want to also accept empty inputs.

`^` and `$` denote the start/end of the input string.

Comment: Yes, `^` is beginning, `$` is end of string. And the quantifier has the format `{min, max}`, where the `max` is optional.