# Regular expression that matches only up to 10 decimal places

Tags: java, regex

so I'm trying to write a regular expression that can match the following scenarios.

```
12.1234 = match
112.12345678901 = wont match
1287729918192.123 = match
123927678281818.19883748383839 = won't match
 23.1829aga = won't match
 1722ahh.98822 = won't match
 1.#$122 = won't match
```

Basically it should only match strings that contain no letters or special characters and values with less than 10 decimal places.

I'm really new to regular expression and am not sure how to accomplish this.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464576/regex-character-limit)

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: Do you want to match 123456.123456 (I am not sure about what you call "decimale places") ?

Comment: Is `00000.00000` OK?

Comment: And what about `123456`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trick to writing simple regexes:

1. describe your pattern in words
2. look for quantifiers, character classes and/or other tokens that satisfy your description
3. combine all the tokens you found into one line!

Basically, your pattern can be described like this:

1. start of the string
2. 1 to unlimited number of digits
3. a dot
4. between 1 and 10 digits
5. end of the string

We just translate the above descriptions into regex:

1. `^`
2. `\d+`
3. `\.`
4. `\d{1,10}`
5. `$`

And combine all these:

```
^\d+\.\d{1,10}$
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked great. Just one thing, I missed a scenario in my original post. It should also match whole digits without a decimal place. How would I alter this to match that?

Comment: @zsh5032 Surround the `.\d{1,10}` part with `()` and add a `?` just before the `$`

Comment: Hey I just tried it and I'm getting a pattern syntax error saying unmatched closing  ")"

Comment: @zsh5032 This: `^\d+(\.\d{1,10})?$`

Comment: Thanks its working I was just gonna message to say I had to move the "(" outside "\" thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]{1,10}$/
```

The Explanation follows:

> - ^ asserts position at start of the string
> - [0-9]* Match a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) any times
> - [.]{0,1} Match a single character . at max one times
> - [0-9]{1,10} Matches between 1 and 10 times, a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57)

Comment: Please try to provide explanation to your coding snippets.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^\d*\.\d{1,10}\s
```

To deconstruct this a little bit:

- "^" means starting at the start of the line of text
- "\d*" means any number of digit characters (including zero!)
- "." means the literal '.' character (we need to escape it with a '\' first)
- "\d{1,10}" means between 1 and 10 amount of digits
- "\s" means any type of whitespace

I would recommend you take a look at https://regexone.com/. An excellent resource that will help you understand how regex works, it helped me a lot!